# Find specific value from cells and check cell value is "91____"

Tags: excel

[Image of Excel Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrmGm.png)

How to select value starting from "91____" from the columns B2:G25 and if value is found compare with the DM_% table if the calue is 70, if yes print yes in action column and if no print false.

Example :- Find from values from B2:G2 if any column has value starting from "91_____" if yes then check the specific DM_% column if value there is 70. If condition is true print "true" in action column or false print "false" in action column.

Comment: What if there is more than one value starting with "91____"? in which column DM_% is found?

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the ["how to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post to avoid downvotes.

You can use [LEFT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c) to get the first characters, put it in an if statement and you are good to go.